# display of rivers on map with d3js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm building a svg map of germany based on data from [Natural Earth](http://naturalearthdata.com). Most thing work fine, including provinces, places names and lakes.  However, when using rivers on a low scaled map, only parts of the river get displayed.  When zooming in, the whole river is visible.

Relevant portions of the code:

```html
<style type="text/css">
     .river { stroke: cadetblue; 
              fill: none; 
              stroke-linejoin: round; 
              stroke-linecap: round; 
            }
</style>
```

```js
var projection = d3.geo.mollweide()
    .center([10.4, 51.1])
    .scale(6300)
    .translate([width/2, height/2]);
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

// [...]

var svg = d3.select("#wrapper").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

var map = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "map");

// [...]

d3.json("data/final.json", function(error, deu) {
    // [...]
    var rivers = topojson.feature(deu, deu.objects.rivers);
    // [...]
    map.append("path")
        .datum(rivers)
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("stroke-width", "2")
        .attr("class" , "river");
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Are you appending the rivers last? Otherwise they may be obscured by something else.

Comment: No, I don't apply them last, but even if I do, things don't change.  (I only append labels after the rivers.)

Comment: Are the paths representing the rivers actually there but not displayed for some reason or are the elements not in the DOM at all?

Comment: Stupid me!  I'm using two data sets from Natural Earth: [rivers and lake centerlines](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_rivers_lake_centerlines.zip) and the [Europe supplement](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_rivers_europe.zip).  However, instead of applying both to the map, I only applied one of it (two times, so this was a typo).  On my second map, which is more detailed and is used for zooming, I appended both, so when zooming in, everything looked fine.